# Custom title page on pptx generated from markdown

Tags: yaml, markdown, powerpoint, pandoc, presentation

From https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block I see how to generate a pptx presentation from a markdown file

```
pandoc habits.txt -o habits.pptx
```

Title is set with

```
% title
% author(s) (separated by semicolons)
% date
```

How can I add a subtitle or another arbitrary text on the title page? I mean to add it to the title page of the slides, the .pptx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some confusion about the title block: what's specified in the question is a [pandoc title block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-pandoc_title_block); it does not support subtitles.

YAML metadata blocks are the generic method of specifying document metadata. Including a subtitle is straight-forward this way:

```yaml
---
title: title
subtitle: the elusive subtitle
author:
  - Author 1
  - Author 2
date: 2021-05-29
---

# Content slides start here
```

Comment: This sounds like end of the line "it does not support subtitles". What if one wants to make it happen, any advice on how to get there?

Comment: I don't quite follow. Does the suggested snipped not work for you, or are you asking how to get a subtitle when using pandoc title blocks? If the latter: you can keep using the old title block and insert a YAML block with just the subtitle definition anywhere in the document.